# What exactly will cause a function's __code__.co_freevars to be non-empty?

Tags: python

I expected the following to result in `y` being a free variable:

```py
def f(x):
    return x + y
```

However, `f.__code__.co_freevars` is equal to `()`, `f.__code__.co_varnames` is equal to `('x',)`, and `f.__code__.co_names` is equal to `('y',)`.

So, what exactly will cause a variable use to populate `co_freevars`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that `co_freevars` is only populated when there is a closure, i.e. an inner function is defined in an outer function.

A module-level function has `__closure__` set to `None` despite accessing a non-local variable:

```py
y = 1

def foo(x):
    return x + y

print(foo.__closure__)
print(foo.__code__.co_freevars)
```

Output:

```
None
()
```

As opposed to:

```py
def bar():
    y = 1

    def baz(x):
        return x + y

    print(baz.__closure__)
    print(baz.__closure__[0].cell_contents)
    print(baz.__code__.co_freevars)


bar()
```

Output:

```
(<cell at 0x7fa8fbbf0700: int object at 0x7fa8fbc7a930>,)
1
('y',)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a supplement to [@mportes's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68282781/2988730).

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#binding-of-names) defines a *free-variable* thusly:

> If a name is bound in a block, it is a local variable of that block, unless declared as [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#nonlocal) or [`global`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#global). If a name is bound at the module level, it is a global variable. (The variables of the module code block are local and global.) If a variable is used in a code block but not defined there, it is a *free variable*.

A caveat from the [following section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names):

> The [`global`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#global) statement has the same scope as a name binding operation in the same block. If the nearest enclosing scope for a free variable contains a global statement, the free variable is treated as a global.

And [even further down](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#interaction-with-dynamic-features), an explicit example:

> Name resolution of free variables occurs at runtime, not at compile time. This means that the following code will print 42:
>
> ```
> i = 10
> def f():
>     print(i)
> i = 42
> f()
> ```

But the formal definition is irrelevant to how the term is used for `co_freevars`. That is explicitly listed in the [documentation for `inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#types-and-members):

> ```
> +------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | code | co_freevars | tuple of names of free variables (referenced via a function’s closure) |
> +------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
> ```

So `code.co_freevars` is a very specific subset of all free variables that reference the E portion of LEGB.